# How can the Rambam's Eighth Principle of Jewish Faith be believed in light of Hazal?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, rambam, heresy, faith-bitachon-emunah, ikarim

The Rambam's eighth Principle of Jewish Faith states that the entire Torah in our possession - every verse - was dictated to Mosheh Rabbenu and that it has not changed.

However, we have explicit passages in Hazal that tell us that the Torah had to be critically reconstructed from a multiplicity of scrolls, each with slightly different wording in certain passages (cf. *y.Ta`anith* 4:2) and that these were apparently used by Ezra HaSofer in his reconstruction (cf. *Avoth De-Rabi Nathan* 30b).

Additionally, we have an explicit text in the *Gemara* that says that the *Amoraim* were not experts in defective and plenary spellings in the words of the Torah (cf. *b.Qidhushin* 30a).

And in the Rambam's own day there were multiple versions of the Torah (differing only in a very few, slight ways), including the *mesorah* of Yemen which differs from Ashkenazi and Sefaradi *mesorah* in five places!

Not to mention the accurate placement of *petuhoth* and *setumoth*, which has enough halakhic weight to *pasul* a sefer Torah if made incorrectly.

My question is:

Surely the Rambam knew these passages from *Hazal* and the facts on the ground, so how could he write such a seemingly dogmatic statement regarding the Torah "in our possession"? Are we missing something? Was he?

**NOTE**: I am aware of the simplistic and non-Maimonidean wording of the popular "Ani Ma'amin" on this principle of faith and ***I reject it*** as not accurately representing the intent of the Rambam in his fuller, more original wording of the eighth principle.

Comment: The Rambam had access to Ben-Asher's codex (in its entirety). It is not completely implausible that he thought he actually had the correct one and everyone else was just wrong.

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/37107/759

Comment: Where does it say, in the Rambam's eighth principle, that our Torah scrolls (or even any of those in his day) are letter-perfect, word-perfect, or even _Parashah_-boundary-perfect copies of the Torah scroll(s) Mosheh Rabenu wrote down?

Comment: @TamirEvan, You are correct, the actual wording of the 8th Principle does not explicitly say this. However, it does say that "every word" contains wisdom, and so I think that it stands to reason that if he thought that even one word could be different from one scroll to another - a reality both currently and in the times of the bayith rishon - then he may have worded it differently. Further, his opening line referring to the "entire Torah in our possession" also raises some concerns in light of Hazal and even what has been said about Rishonim, such as Yehudah He-Hasidh and Ibn `Ezra. Kol tuv.

Comment: in regards to the 3 sifrei toroth used for reconstruction of the toro 7azal had, rambam as @DoubleAA mentioned believed the ban osheir/allepo codex to be most accurate if not the accurate version of the toro. and could have thought that the reconstructed toro was the real version from mosha rabbeinu 3alow ha sholom while the first 3 were just written wrongly.

Comment: It should be noted that Avos D'rabbi Nassan postdates Chazal.

Comment: @DoubleAA While possible the Rambam thought Ben-Asher's codex was correct (or at least the most accurate available), it (at least) borders on a *zilzul* of his views to suggest that he thought anyone who preferred a different extant tradition was therefore a heretic.

Comment: @Loewian I don't see why that should be? (Leave aside for now the sugya of a heretic beshogeig.)

Comment: You're basically saying Ezra HaSofer did a bad job in his reconstruction. From what I understand, he was able to piece together the original Torah MiSinai.

Comment: This is a great question, but I think it very badly needs enough of the quote from the Rambam so that the reader can tell what you think is evidence for your question. I too had assumed like Rav Weinberg z"l that the Rambam was not at all discussing the process of copying and transmitting Moshe's version.

Comment: the simple answer is that the Torah we have is the same one that Moshe Rabenu was given and those points you raised don't pose a problem for us to have the accurate text of the Torah.

Comment: Also, it would be helpful to quote the Ani Maamin; again, so you could explain what you think you're rejecting.

Answer (score 17):

R' Yaakov Weinberg, in an audio recording, addressed this issue (as an issue with the ani maamin, which R' Weinberg, like you, rejected), and he explained that the point of the Rambam is *not* to say that the specific texts which we have now are identical to the one transmitted to Moshe.  Rather, the point of the Rambam is to say that Moshe was a faithful transmitter of the Torah, and did not err nor alter the Torah as it was told to him.  Thus the Rambam writes:

> כלומר שהגיע אליו כולה מאת ה' הגעה שקורין אותה על דרך השאלה דבור
>
> Which means to say that the entire Torah reached Moshe from Hashem on a level which we call "speech"

and the Rambam's proof text for this Yesod is

> בזאת תדעון כי ה' שלחני וכו ולא מלבי
>
> With this (the earth swallowing Adas Korach) you shall know that Hashem has sent me ... and I did not make it up

In other words, the source text is a verse stating that Moshe did not make up the Torah.  The point of this Yesod is the accuracy of Moshe's transmission.

Comment: So, what this seems to be saying is that people tend to read into the Rambam's exact wording TOO much and should instead see things in the big picture and try to focus on his intent for this principle. In other words, we should see the Rambam as trying to PRESERVE a truth already held, rather than trying to INVENT a new "dogma" within Judaism. I like it. Thank you. Kol tuv.

Comment: @Maimonist I would go a step further and say that it isn't seeing the big picture at the cost of ignoring the details - it _is_ the details of what the Rambam says.  There is no need to not take the Rambam literally, just to read it carefully and see what his focus is.

Comment: (1) The formulation in [Hilkhot Teshuvah 3:17](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/1503.htm)[8] seems to support this understanding, as well. (2) Also, I'd be leery of scrutinizing the Rambam's language when working off a translation. I have access to two Hebrew translations: one says "_Kol **Ot** she-Bah Yesh Bah Chokhmot_", and another says "_Kol **Dibur ve-Dibur** min ha-Torah Yesh Bahen Chokhmot_".

Comment: @TamirEvan Agreed, with two caveats - I think you can still scrutinize the clear idea being expressed (whether it's אות or דיבור, the point is the transmission, not the current state), and I am comfortable between Shilat and Kapach to assume I have a good translation.

Comment: I was more responding to Maimonist's comments about "people tend to read into the Rambam's exact wording TOO much" here, and "it does say that 'every word' contains wisdom" in response to my comment on the question. (I should have, in retrospect, directed that part of my comment @Maimonist specifically.)

Comment: @TamirEvan, I re-read the Qafih and was again reminded of the actual language of the passage and I still don't see how it can make sense with Hazal or reality. And it would seem that Qafih is preserving the actual sense (since there was simply no one on his level with regard to Arabic) with "oth" and Shilat (although a fantastic scholar whose writings and translations I thoroughly enjoy otherwise) seems to be the one trying to make peace between his religious and scientific sentiments with "dibur wa-dhibur." I could be wrong, but they cannot both be right and "oth" seems to be damning.

Comment: I agree with @Maimonist. while it's true that the main point of the rambam's yesod is the accuracy/divinity of Moshe's writing, but it also seems like believing in the perfect accuracy of our own seforim is an also part of that. This is how Rabbi J. D. Bleich understands the Rambam as well (in "With Perfect Faith", pg. 365). On the other hand, there's no mention of this in Hilchos Teshuva

Comment: @Matt במחילת כבוד R' Bleich, I disagree.  I think the Rambam's point of the sanctity of each letter/word/verse (depending on your translation) is a result of the authority of Moshe's transmission, and therefore _relevant_ to this yesod, but the Rambam is making no guarantee of how well we will copy it over afterwards.

Comment: @Maimonist Noteworthy that in Hilchos Teshuva, the Rambam's own Hebrew, he says אפילו פסוק אחד and אפילו מילה אחד and not אות אחת. Although anyways you see clearly from there that the point isn't what we have currently but rather what Moshe transmitted, as I said.

Comment: @Yez The Diyuk in "Milah Echad" vs "Ot Achat" is weak since there are differences about words too, like is פוטיפרע one word or two פוטי פרע?

Comment: I just looked over the eighth principle again, don't see anything that is a problem for Rav Weinberg's answer. Could you quote something that you think is different?

Comment: We had lost track of a lot of malei vs chaser (Qiddushin 30a) by R Meir's day. For that matter, Ezra's official copy of the Torah was based on three earlier copies, and thanks to taking a majority on various questions ended up with a combination that didn't exist in any of them. (Sifrei Devarim 356). The Rambam couldn't be talking about spelling. My guess, since he included Oral Torah, is that he is talking about semantics -- the ideas and meanings.

Answer (score 7):

I've asked this question to several talmidei chachamim, and all of them have given me the same general response: the Rambam shouldn't be taken too literally, as after all, he certainly knew the passages in Chazal which you've quoted. What he means is that, for all intents and purposes, we have the same Torah. The very slight differences of a plene spelling here or an extra ו there are not meaningful differences that would cause us to say that our Torah is 'a different Torah'. This point is also made in an [aish.com article](http://www.aish.com/h/sh/tat/48969731.html) which claims that the words 'colour' to 'color' can still be considered to be the same word. (In reality, the differences in the Torah's text are more significant, but the idea is plausible enough). Even a difference that is *halakhically* significant (in terms of making the Torah pasul) it still may not be meaningfully significant for the purposes of calling it "the same Torah"

Comment: The Aish article says that the idea is based on a series of lectures by Rabbi Yaakov Weinberg Z"L. I would be curious to know if this was the Rosh Yeshiva's own chiddush or are there other sources that say the same thing.

Comment: @eramm see YEZ's answer. I had heard this myself in the name of R. Weinberg from a Rabbi in NIRC but wasn't sure if it was documented anywhere else

Comment: But given the importance of every letter and vowel point to interpreting the Torah, couldn't a single difference have wide reaching consequences to interpretation? And what of the concept that the Torah is the Divine blueprint for Creation? Would differing blueprints cause different things to be created in the same place, causing destruction from overlapping elements? Figuratively speaking, you cant build two walls in the same place, at the same time, without their atoms coming together and exploding. That's just a physical analogy to what Im asking about.

Answer (score 0):

Like others have pointed out, Rambam's 8th principle speaks to Moshe's personal transmission of the Torah and nothing more.

However, the logic for why people thought this was a good question in the first place, which I'll briefly recite:

Premise: Rambam would never disagree on anything any Chazal member would say
A) Chazal says the last 8 verses were written by Joshua, not Moshe
B) Rambam says the whole torah was written by moshe (misunderstood)

Conclusion: There is a problem here, because rambam would never disagree with Chazal, much less call any of them a kofer.

I can think of two instances where Rambam called out chazal for stating a heretical idea, or a Rishon saying it for him.

In Moreh Nevuchim when discussing the concept of creation ex nihilo (out of nothing), he quotes 2 sages in Midrash Rabba that say time existed always. Rambam says this is heresy, plain and simple.

Also, at the beginning of R Yosef Albo's Sefer on Ikkarim, he begins it by saying Rambam is wrong about the 13th principle, Mashiach, because according to Rambam then Rebbe Hillel (Sanhedrin 99a) would be a heretic! Because he says there is no Messiah coming.

So clearly Rav Yosef Albo thought Rambam had the audacity to go against the sages and even call one of their ideas heretical. Of course, this is only against individual members of Chazal, not the "Chachamim", or the majority.

So, even though I agree that Rambam would have no problem when it comes to the 8th Ikar and reality, the premise of the question (at least as so far related to Chazal saying Moshe didn't write last 8 pesukim) is wrong.

I say this not to be technical, but to show an important point that we can all learn from.

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya Eitan and thanks for this first answer. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!