# Is Rabbi David Halivni's theory of "Chate’u Yisrael" kfira?

Tags: faith-bitachon-emunah, ikarim, biblical-criticism, ezra-the-scribe

Rabbi David Weiss Halivni proposed a theory of *Chate’u Yisrael* [1](https://www.academia.edu/42656793/David_Weiss_Halivni_Chate_u_Yisrael_Israel_Sinned_A_Possible_Solution_to_the_Conflict_of_Peshat_and_Derash_in_Halakhah_and_the_Modern_Jew_Essays_in_Honor_of_Horace_Bier_Mt_Vernon_NJ_Union_for_Traditional_Conservative_Judaism_1989_53_69) to resolve tensions between traditional exegesis and source critical methods of examining the Torah. His theory provides a way to believe in Torah-mi-sinai as well as discrepancies.

The theory states that "Israel sinned" and allowed the Torah-mi-sinai to be corrupted during periods where Israel proved to be unworthy custodians. Later on, Ezra ha-sofer restored Torah to his best abilities. R' Halivni draws on numerous pieces of evidence scattered in Tanakh about non-observance, and later rabbinic literature about the role of Ezra in *tikkunei soferim*. The conclusion is that the Torah we have today obviously has human fingerprints in it, but it's our only record of Torah mi-sinai.

Is this belief kosher? Does it violate Rambam's 8th Ikkar? Have any Torah scholars discussed the theory of *chatu yisrael*?

[1](https://www.academia.edu/42656793/David_Weiss_Halivni_Chate_u_Yisrael_Israel_Sinned_A_Possible_Solution_to_the_Conflict_of_Peshat_and_Derash_in_Halakhah_and_the_Modern_Jew_Essays_in_Honor_of_Horace_Bier_Mt_Vernon_NJ_Union_for_Traditional_Conservative_Judaism_1989_53_69). [‘Chate’u Yisrael’ (Israel Sinned): A Possible Solution to the Conflict of Peshat and Derash](https://www.academia.edu/42656793/David_Weiss_Halivni_Chate_u_Yisrael_Israel_Sinned_A_Possible_Solution_to_the_Conflict_of_Peshat_and_Derash_in_Halakhah_and_the_Modern_Jew_Essays_in_Honor_of_Horace_Bier_Mt_Vernon_NJ_Union_for_Traditional_Conservative_Judaism_1989_53_69)

Comment: What exactly does "human fingerprints" mean?

Comment: In the scope of DWH’s work, I think the working definition should be “indications of non-divinely sourced insertions into the text of the Torah”

Comment: Why would it not be kefirah? The gemara says  כי דבר ה' בזה זה האומר אין תורה מן השמים ואפילו אמר כל התורה כולה מן השמים חוץ מפסוק זה

Comment: Please cite the book and page number where R. Weiss-Halivni expresses this view.

Comment: @wfb https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/44623/759

Comment: @DoubleAA יש לחלק, ולא חילוק כחודו של מחט אלא כפתחו של אולם