# what is the single letter difference between ashkenazi and sephardi torah scrolls

Tags: sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, ashkenazi, sefer-torah

According to http://onthemainline.blogspot.co.uk/2005/12/textual-criticism-of-torah-response-to.html

> The only letter difference between Ashkenazim and Sephardim is whether
>   a particular word ends with a silent aleph or silent heh.

What book/chapter/verse/word ?

Comment: This is only true of current practice. Historically things haven't been so uniform.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The relevant word is דכא which in some scrolls is written דכה. See [Deuteronomy 23:2](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0523.htm#2).

---

While the portion of Aleppo Codex containing that word is currently lost, we do have the Aleppo Codex to Tehillim 90:3 where the same word appears spelled with an Alef. The Mesorah there notes that this spelling is used in three places and lists them: Deuteronomy 23:2, Tehillim 90:3 and Isaiah 57:15.

[image: aleppo codex to tehillim 90 3]

Many Ashkenazi scrolls used the Hey spelling, but upon seeing manuscript evidence some have started changing back to Alef (eg. [the first Lubavitcher Rebbe](http://www.chabad.org/therebbe/article_cdo/aid/5906/jewish/Hayom-Yom-Elul-7.htm)). In the last 75 years when we have gained access to the Aleppo codex it seems the Alef side is even better supported.

See [here](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:WFTf2J3h0Y4J:www.girsology.com/site/%3Fq%3Dspelling-petzua-daka+&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us) for more discussion of the manuscript evidence in both directions.

See [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/37107/759) for more variants in modern Torah scrolls.

Comment: thanks for the info re דכה in  `לא יבוא פצוע דכה`  Deuteronomy 23:2 And   Re the google archived girsology link you give, (the girsology site itself seemed to be only up briefly), I found  (by the same author joshua waxman) the articles posted http://parsha.blogspot.co.uk/search/label/girsology   e.g. http://parsha.blogspot.co.uk/2014/08/the-spelling-of.html

Comment: In the early years of his leadership, the latest Lubavitcher Rebbe asked people with access to old manuscripts to check if they were written with an Aleph or a Hey. They all came back with Aleph (If I remember correctly). You can see these letters in his printed letters.

Comment: From what I've seen, older Chumashim/tikkunim printed in the Ashkenazi world would print the Heh spelling as dominant, with a footnote about the Alef; or the two of them as equal possibilities. Newer chumashim/tikkunim have it printed with an Alef, with maybe a little footnote "by the way some Ashkenazi scrolls have a Heh."

Comment: While the first Chabad Rebbe did say it's with an aleph, I'm not aware of him seeing any manuscripts. The 6th Rebbe did.

Comment: You write "The Mesorah there notes that this spelling is used in three places and lists them: Deuteronomy 23:2, Tehillim 90:3 and Isaiah 57:15." <-- It says Which spelling is used in 3 places?  Looking at a Feldheim Chumash, it has Heh in Deut 23:2 and Aleph in the other two places. So there are no other places where Dacah is spelt with a heh.

Comment: http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=33644&st=&pgnum=13

Comment: The lisbon codex has a heh, as does the hilleli codex, according to the webpage you link to in your answer .  Yet in your rejection of my edit you said it's not obvious that that's the case? Also I can no longer see your full remark on the edit I tried to make that you rejected, as it is cut with ellipses  what dto you mean by kapi hatorah in reference to the samaritans / their text(which also has a heh)? And josh waxman who authored that page is of the view that it should have a heh.Though you only mention manuscripts with an aleph as if it's[fairly] conclusive that aleph is better supported.

Comment: @barlop you don't need to say "there are also manuscripts with a hei" as it's obvious, but i made it more explicit anyway. i included some details about the most important manuscript and linked to some discussion of the rest. it is fairly conclusive that alef is better supported. josh just finished off by saying that hei is weirder so that might indicate it's actually right. it's not better supported though. The samaritans are known to 'fix' apparent errors all the time, so the fact that they also change כפי תחרא to תחרה to get a more Hebrew sounding spelling fits with them changing this too

Comment: @DoubleAA But if anything is fixing an apparent error then it'd result in consistent spelling.

Comment: @barlop in the samaritan torah it is indeed consistent throughout (there is no tehillim and isaiah for samaritans). it's possible though that someone would only change an aramaic-ism in the torah not later writings which are much more flexible in terms of when they were finalized and their linguistic influences. the fact is we can speculate all day who changed what when but one way or another the most ancient and most accurate tiberian manuscripts overwhelmingly have an alef and acharei rabbim lehatos.

Comment: samaritans also change the alef ending into a hei for תחרא סבתכא תימא שהדותא גרא לזרא in the torah so this isn't a surprise at all. it would be quite a shock if the samaritans didn't have דכה

Comment: @DoubleAA any idea why josh http://www.girsology.com/site/?q=spelling-petzua-daka  claims to show codex hilleli when google results say is a lost text dating to 600ad.. lost. ?  (note the image he has shows a heh)

Comment: @barlop pretty sure it's from https://books.google.com/books/about/The_Pentateuch.html?id=aQ2kSwAACAAJ which is a tanakh that the scribe claims he copied from the original hilleli in 1241