# Why Is A Yemenite Torah Scroll Kosher?

Tags: sefer-torah, yemenite-temani

How come a yemenite Torah scroll is kosher to read from, even though it is [different](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/37101/what-are-the-differences-between-teimani-and-ashkenazi-sefardi-sifrei-torah) from all other Torah scrolls?

Comment: The better question is why are the other Torah scrolls kosher.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya PBUH, and thanks for the interesting question! If you haven’t done so already, you should take a look at the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour). Also please consider [registering](//judaism.stackexchange.com/users/signup-unregistered) your account, to [enable](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) more site features, including voting. I hope you'll look around and find other Q&A of interest and stay learning with us.

Comment: how is it different?

Comment: @Dude https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/37101/what-are-the-differences-between-teimani-and-ashkenazi-sefardi-sifrei-torah